# Why integer variable is storing string values in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have declared a variable of integer type. VBA Excel is not restricting to store only integers in it. It accepts String Values (such as "10") and correctly displays 10 in message box.
I want a solution in which integer variable can only store integer values.
A sample code is

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Button1_Click()
        Dim a As Integer
        a = "10"
        MsgBox (a)
   End Sub
```

Here 'a' is declared as integer and "10" has been stored in 'a' without error.
Is there a way that it shows error on each string assignment such as in other programming languages.

Comment: it know to read the value within the `"`, try putting `a = "string1"` and see what happens...

Comment: This is caused by [implicit conversion](http://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/converting-implicit-conversion.htm).

Comment: This is called implicit type conversion. The "10" is implicit converted to integer 10. So the integer variable does **not** store a string but a implicit converted integer. Not only `VBA` will do this but also some other programming languages. As far as I know, you cannot avoid this in `VBA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick idea could be to store the new value in a variable of type Variant and prior to assignment to the Integer variable check its sub type.

```
 Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim newIntegerValue As Variant
    newIntegerValue = "10"

    If VarType(newIntegerValue) = vbString Then
        Err.Raise 123, "Button1_Click", "Invalid cast"
    End If

    Dim a As Integer
    a = newIntegerValue
End Sub
```

---

This functionality could be wrapped in a class named e.g. `StrictInteger`.

> StrictInteger class module

```
Option Explicit

Private m_value As Integer
Private m_hasValue As Boolean
Private Const invalidValueErrorNumber As Long = vbObjectError + 600

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_value = 0
    m_hasValue = False
End Sub

Public Function Assign(ByVal newIntegerValue As Variant)
    ' TODO: check with next variant sub types
    If VarType(newIntegerValue) = vbString Or _
        VarType(newIntegerValue) = vbBoolean Then
        Err.Raise invalidValueErrorNumber, _
            "StrictInteger::Initialize", _
            "Value initialization failed"
    End If
    On Error GoTo Err_Initialize
    m_value = newIntegerValue
    m_hasValue = True
    Exit Function
Err_Initialize:
    m_hasValue = False
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "StrictInteger::Initialize", Err.Description
End Function

Public Property Get Value() As Integer
    If m_hasValue Then
        Value = m_value
        Exit Property
    End If
    Err.Raise invalidValueErrorNumber, _
        "StrictInteger::Value", _
        "Valid value is not available"
End Property
```

> Standard module test

```
Sub Test()
    On Error GoTo Err_Test
    Dim strictInt As StrictInteger
    Set strictInt = New StrictInteger
    strictInt.Assign "10"
    strictInt.Assign "ABC"
    strictInt.Assign ActiveSheet
    strictInt.Assign Now
    strictInt.Assign True
    strictInt.Assign False
    strictInt.Assign 10
    MsgBox strictInt.Value
    Exit Sub
Err_Test:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```